# Custom alias for home page

Tags: path-aliases, redirection

I have a bilingual website (French and English)

I have set
"/fr/nom-de-page" as the home page in /fr/admin/config/system/site-information

But Drupal 9.4.5 insist on redirecting to /fr/

I want to keep "/fr/nom-de-page" as the URL of my home page.

Any clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, Drupal 9.4.5 doesn't redirect when you set a node as front page. You can visit both, '/' and '/path/to/node' as front page. This is often considered as a bad SEO practice, so  many people install the module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) which prevents that by redirecting URLs to their canonical counterpart. If you have installed this module go to the modules setting and disable *Enforce clean and canonical URLs* if you don't want that.

Comment: If I disable "Enforce clean and canonical URLs", the pages respond to 3 URLS and no redirection occur "/node/id",  "/fr/" and "/fr/nom-de-page". This is bad SEO. What I want is my front page to ALWAYS redirect to "/fr/nom-de-page".